# For what it's worth, 'four' is missing transparency

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

On the [Winter Bash 2020 countdown page](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/) (which is **awesome**, by the way!), I couldn't help spotting this:

[image: Four lacking transparency]

All digits except four have transparency in their internal parts. Poor four doesn't. Can it please join its sibling digits?

P.S.

This isn't a thick line case. Zooming in 500% proves it:

[image: Big digit, but still no transparency]

Comment: Just from eyeballing it, it looks like it's just that the line is so thick that it fills in the gap entirely.

Comment: @F1Krazy not really, I'll take another SS zoomed in.

Comment: Why do you expect a gap? The outline is so thick that it covers this triangle completely. See this [screenshot of the inner triangle with the outline extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdwXj.png). The cyan bars have the same stroke width as the `4`.

Comment: @user289905 if nothing else, then being consistent will other digits, e.g. 6, 9, 8. All having small gaps too, all transparent. :)

Comment: Neither 6, 9 or 8 has a 'thinner' line though to make those gaps a reality, in fact 6 and 9 also are missing a gap between the 'tail' and the 'round'. @user289905 is right, the 4 is just closed because of three overlapping lines...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell oh, looks like we talk about different things. Anyway, I'd still be glad to have the digit four have transparency inside of it. I didn't fully understand all those thin lines, maybe too thick headed... ;-)

Comment: Hmm... is Winterbash nitpicking upvote worthy or downvote worthy ;)

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile either way, the vote ends up being about nothing.

Comment: @VLAZ all votes are nothing, just adding or taking away virtual reputation.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard I mean, in this case it's either for a hole filled with nothingness, or no hole.

Comment: @VLAZ I prefer filling this hole up...

Comment: Looks like [meta-tag:status-by-design] to me...

Comment: This site doesn't do transparency well.

Comment: @Mast probably! Still, was fun to ask. :-)

Answer (score 20):

I can confirm that it is indeed the thickness of the line that makes the (donut)hole disappear.

If you access the image of the four directly from the server you can tweak its HTML code.

Originally the "stroke-width" is set to 7, changing it to 3 results in the following image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice catch, and I finally understand what you were all talking about. I saw the light! :-D

Comment: But still, I consider this as a bug since the final result is inconsistent digit. The technical issue behind the scenes is less relevant. :)

Comment: Meh @Shadow10YearsWizard you say it's inconsistent, I say it's consistent with the top part of 6, the bottom part of 9, the way the bottom of 5 touches the top part, and the sharp angles in 2 and 7 have lines touching in the same way as in the center of 4... seems pretty consistent to me :P

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard The eight has the smallest unobscured interstitial, anything smaller (as [Tinkeringbell commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357095/for-what-its-worth-four-is-missing-transparency#comment1193021_357097)) is going to touch, here's a much [further zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRn36.png) example; where each digit is larger than the screen size.

Comment: Maybe if we [zoom and enhance](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zoom-and-enhance) even more, we'll see the gap.